# Redemption Law (גאולת קרקעות) in Book Of Ruth

Tags: estates-inheritance, book-of-ruth

I am struggling to understand the redemption law (גאולת קרקעות) in Ruth Scroll, and what was needed to be accomplished?

1. Who the field belonged to originally, before Naomi left, and at the time of the Boaz negotiation? Naomi, Elimelech or someone else?
2. What "Goel" was obliged to do ? Buy the field from Naomi in case it belonged to her, or buy back it to her if it belonged to someone else?

I am leaving the marriage aside currently, only property ownership transfer is of interest.

Thanks

Comment: The malbim understands that the field belonged to Naomi but that she was interested in selling it. The issue was to buy it and keep it in the family instead of having an outsider but it. He explains that it was one big field that was split in three between the sons on nachshon and she wanted to sell her piece that she got from her husband.

Comment: @Chatzkel makes sense thanks, can you point to the exact source? BTW can additional condition of marrying Ruth be connected to "stay in the family" ?

Comment: https://www.sefaria.org/Malbim_on_Ruth.4.3.1?lang=bi

Comment: https://businesshalacha.com/en/business-weekly/archive/730